# How to retrieve row when null then take above record in table,with out using loop and update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
id  name
--------------
1   ACTIVE
2   NULL
3   NULL
4   NULL
5   COMPLETED
6   NULL
7   COMPLETED
8   COMPLETED
9   ACTIVE
10  NULL
11  ACTIVE
```

Output:

```
id  name
--------------
1   ACTIVE
2   ACTIVE
3   ACTIVE
4   ACTIVE
5   COMPLETED
6   COMPLETED
7   COMPLETED
8   COMPLETED
9   ACTIVE
10  ACTIVE
11  ACTIVE
```

Task: retrieve null records with above values without using a loop and update.
in will come select statement.

Comment: What is the criteria to determine when a NULL should be 'ACTIVE' or 'COMPLETED'? The basic SQL statement is: UPDATE [table] SET name = ? WHERE name IS NULL, but first you need to now when to use ACTIVE or COMPLETED.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47354729/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it, because without that we cannot help. Please see **[ask]**.

Comment: which version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

With DDL and Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (ID int, [Name] varchar(9));
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES (1,'ACTIVE'),
       (2,NULL),
       (3,NULL),
       (4,NULL),
       (5,'COMPLETED'),
       (6,NULL),
       (7,'COMPLETED'),
       (8,'COMPLETED'),
       (9,'ACTIVE'),
       (10,NULL),
       (11,'ACTIVE');
GO

SELECT *
FROM #Sample;

UPDATE S
SET [Name] = (SELECT TOP 1 [Name]
              FROM #Sample sq
              WHERE sq.ID < S.ID
                AND sq.[Name] IS NOT NULL
              ORDER BY sq.ID DESC)
FROM #Sample S
WHERE S.[Name] IS NULL;

SELECT *
FROM #Sample;

GO
DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Comment: /sigh Stackoverflow and the not allowing comments... So archaic; if I have something to add to someone else's answer, I should be able to... Anyway,  @Vamsi's query is significantly slower than mine. His has 16 scan counts and 126 logical reads, compared to mine with 4 scans and 53 reads.

Comment: You need 50 reputation to be able to comment on other poster's answers.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: I'm aware, just no idea why that is a "thing". it's deterred me for years on answering questions, because you can't ask an OP questions about their question... Instead you have to "answer" to instead ask a question, only for a moderator to down vote you and then delete your "answer".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming window functions are supported in your version of SQL Server, this can be done with classifying consecutive `null`s in the name column to the same group as the first occurring name for an id. Then use `max` to get the name for the group and use it to `update`.

```
with cte as (
select id,name,max(name) over(partition by grp) as new_name 
from (select *, sum(case when name is null then 0 else 1 end) over(order by id) as grp
      from tbl
     ) t
)
update cte set name = new_name
where name is null;
```

Comment: its possible to get select statement.with out update and loop.